# Кнопка и слайд вниз

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, css-animation

Подскажите пожалуйста, как лучше реализовать линии на кнопке и линии вниз,заранее благодарен

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Лучший вариант на `svg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Удобный вариант с `linear-gradient`:

```css
.hidden {
  width: 3px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(#000 0, #000 20px, #fff 0%, #fff 25px);
  animation: move 3s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    height: 50px;
    opacity: .9;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="hidden"></div>
```

Вот кнопка:

```css
.btn {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid darkred;
  margin: 50px 100px;
  border-radius: 50px/100px;
  background: tomato;
  position: relative;
}

.btn:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 250px;
  height: 5px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #000 0%, #000, #000);
  position: absolute;
  left: -50%;
  top: 40%;
  z-index: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.btn:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 250px;
  height: 5px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #000 0%, #000, #000);
  position: absolute;
  left: -30%;
  top: 60%;
  z-index: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn"></div>
```